# Update query issue of GROUP BY sum() function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT p.userId, u.username, SUM(p.prices)Price 
FROM tblPrices p, tblUsers u 
WHERE u.userId = p.userId
GROUP BY p.userId, u.username
```

I want update `Price` in the result

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you want to update tblPrices.prices? What have you tried and how has it failed?

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins. Explicit joins are a part of the standard SQL for almost 30 years now, it's high time to embrace them!

Comment: After execute this Will be Create table , I want Update Price in This Table Result

Comment: Currently, that query will generate a total price for each userid and username. Where should that be stored? If id 1, name Mo, had two prices, 13 and 7 you'd have a result of 20. But now what? Certainly you don't want to update each row of the prices table overwriting with 20 as that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb7049e35720e92e5bee4a678b5283d3

In SQL Server, you have two avenues for creating a table. An explicit `CREATE TABLE` statement wherein you explicitly define the table structure. The other is managed through the SELECT statement's optional `INTO` clause. The SQL Engine will identify the shape of the result set and then create a table that exactly matches what your results look like. 
This will also immediately load any results of your query into the table, but this only works once. If you need to add more data to the table, you have to rewrite your query into a traditional `INSERT` statement, and possibly an `UPDATE` depending on the variability of the source data. The other approach would be to drop the table and recreate it every time. The correct choice is dependent upon the business requirements and data suitability.

Simulating your environment

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblPrices
(
userId int NOT NULL
, prices decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
);

create table dbo.tblUsers
(
userId int NOT NULL
,username varchar(50) nOT NULL
);

insert into
dbo.tblUsers 
VALUES (1,'mo')
,(2, 'bill')
,(3, 'no sales');

insert into dbo.tblPrices
VALUES
(1, 13)
,(1, 7)
, (2, 17);
```

Querying the data

```
-- create the table if it doesn't exist
-- blows up otherwise
SELECT
    P.userId
,   U.username
,   SUM(P.prices) AS Prices
INTO
    dbo.RESULTS
FROM
    dbo.tblPrices AS P
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.tblUsers AS U
        ON U.userId = P.userId
GROUP BY
    P.userId
,   U.username

;

-- What if we want to see all users, whether they had sales or not
-- Notice the change to a left join as well as reordering of the
-- tables and the use of the users userId as the prices might not exist
SELECT
    U.userId
,   U.username
,   SUM(P.prices) AS Prices
INTO
    dbo.RESULTS_ALL_USERS
FROM
    dbo.tblUsers AS U
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.tblPrices aS P
        ON U.userId = P.userId
GROUP BY
    U.userId
,   U.username
;
```

Checking the results

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.RESULTS AS R ORDER BY userID;
SELECT * FROM dbo.RESULTS_ALL_USERS AS R ORDER BY userID;
```

Comment: i want Update `Prices`

Comment: But your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211176/update-query-issue-of-group-by-sum-function-in-sql-server/60211720#comment106500500_60211176) specifies `After execute this Will be Create table , I want Update Price in This Table Result`  You realize that if you update the values in the tblPrices, the data no longer reflects reality, right?

Comment: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp2mp.png) might make it more clear what I think you're asking for and why it's likely a bad idea. You're going to lose all the original pricing values and to make it worse, if someone looks at the totals in there, they'll see an inflated value

Comment: `SELECT r.SuplierId  ,s.SuplierName,SUM(CONVERT(float,r.Rest)) Dept FROM tblRequest r, tblSuplier s 
    Where s.SuplierId = r.SuplierId  GROUP BY r.SuplierId,S.SuplierName`

**after execute i want put result in table and update  `Dept`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each userid has one corresponding username, you can use an UPDATE statement with a JOIN to replace the prices value:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Prices=B.Price_Sum
FROM tblPrices A 
INNER JOIN 
    (Select userId,SUM(prices) as Price_Sum
    from tblPrices 
    GROUP BY userId) B
ON A.UserID=B.UserID
```

This would replace the Prices field with the sum of all the prices for that user. Hope this helps.

Edit: As Billinkc has mentioned in the comments, this would replace all the individual prices with the overall sum. Use this query only when you are sure that's what you want. Also, note that the update statement is meant to be run only once. If run multiple times, you will get wrong result.

Comment: If I had two prices in there, a 7 and a 13, the total for me is 20. After running your query, my total then becomes 40. That's likely not what they intended, even if it was asked. Might put some bigger warnings along the lines of "this will corrupt your original data, make sure this really what you meant to do"  $.02

Comment: I agree with the fact that this was probably not the intended result. I will add a warning to my answer. However I did not understand how the value would become 40. Did you mean if it was run twice?

Comment: `SELECT r.SuplierId  ,s.SuplierName,SUM(CONVERT(float,r.Rest)) Dept FROM tblRequest r, tblSuplier s 
    Where s.SuplierId = r.SuplierId  GROUP BY r.SuplierId,S.SuplierName `

**i want `UPDATE Dept `**